# how to search a multidimensional array data according to another multidimensional array data result

Tags: php

I have 2 multidimensional arrays that takes data from 2 different tables in DB. One of them has 3 teams, the other one has the orders that teams have make.

```
$sql = "select id, supervizori, grupi, tipo_crt, operatori, data, status, nome, cognome, cel, codice_fiscale from kontrata";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    if(!$sql) {
        die("Error1");
    } //this query takes the orders from the kontrata table.

$sql_2 = "select * from grupi";
$result_2 = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql_2);
    if(!$sql_2) {
        die("Error2");
    } // this query take the teams from the grupi table.

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {            
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['supervizori'] = $row['supervizori'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['grupi'] = $row['grupi'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['tipo_crt'] = $row['tipo_crt'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['operatori'] = $row['operatori'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['data'] = $row['data'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['status'] = $row['status'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['nome'] = $row['nome'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['cognome'] = $row['cognome'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['cel'] = $row['cel'];
        $kontratat[$row['id']]['codice_fiscale'] = row['codice_fiscale'];
} // In this loop i take the data according to the order table.

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_2)) {      
    $kontratat_2[$kontratat['id']]['grup_name'] = $row['grup_name'];
} // In this loop i take the teams.
```

After the loops i use foreach to dispay the data to a table but when i call foreach to result i get all the orders (This is normal) but i have 100 orders
that those 3 teams have make. I want to filter the orders for each team using the secont loop. In few words i wand to view all the orders from each team using a "ID" from the first query, not dispay the same team 50 times. Thanks :)

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
      (
        [supervizori] => data
        [grupi] => Doctors //this is the team
        [tipo_crt] => LUCE
        [operatori] => data
        [data] => 2015-12-20
        [status] => OK
        [nome] => data
        [cognome] => data
        [cel] => data
        [codice_fiscale] => shkrfl93a08a123a
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [supervizori] => data
        [grupi] => BMW //this is the team
        [tipo_crt] => data
        [operatori] => data
        [data] => 2015-12-22
        [status] => KO
        [nome] => rgrg
        [cognome] => grdgdrgdrg
        [cel] => serges
        [codice_fiscale] => a
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [supervizori] => data
        [grupi] => Doctors  //this is the team    
        [tipo_crt] => GAS
        [operatori] => data
        [data] => 2015-12-24
        [status] => Atessa
        [nome] => dscc
        [cognome] => csdfvsg
        [cel] => wgwegwe
        [codice_fiscale] => rgrwgrwg
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [supervizori] => data
        [grupi] => Bosat //this is the team
        [tipo_crt] => data
        [operatori] => data
        [data] => 2015-12-24
        [status] => OK
        [nome] => dscc
        [cognome] => csdfvsg
        [cel] => wgwegwe
        [codice_fiscale] => rgrwgrwg
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [supervizori] => data
        [grupi] => Doctors   //this is the team   
        [tipo_crt] => LUCE
        [operatori] => data
        [data] => 2015-12-29
        [status] => Atessa
        [nome] => dhr
        [cognome] => rhrdh
        [cel] => rdhrdh
        [codice_fiscale] => rdhrdh
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [supervizori] => data
        [grupi] => Doctors   //this is the team   
        [tipo_crt] => LUCE
        [operatori] => data
        [data] => 2016-01-04
        [status] => OK
        [nome] => dwadwa
        [cognome] => jgv
        [cel] => jlgv
        [codice_fiscale] => jgv
    ) // this is the first array from orders

Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [grup_name] => BMW   
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [grup_name] => Doctors      
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [grup_name] => Bosat    
        )

 )// the teams array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
$completeData = array();

foreach($orders as $order)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($order['grupi'], $completeData))
    {
        $completeData[$order['grupi']] = array();
    }
    $completeData[$order['grupi']][] = $order;
}
```

Tune it according to your needs.